# Java filter file by name and extension

Tags: java, file, filter, java.nio.file

I'm developing a little Java program for my company.
In this program I need to retrieve from my local folder some files, but i need to search the files by the first three character and by extension.
Reading the java documentation I saw that the `java.nio.file.Files` library exists and So to filter the files by name and extension I saw that there are the `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` constructs which I have implemented as follows so I tried to use it.

```
// recuperiamo tutti i file nella directory attuale e filtro per
// F4_*.cbi, CN_*.cbi, A4_*.cbi, Q4_*.cbi
dirFiles = new File("C:/www/htdocs/comune/F24_CT/deleghe_da_inviare_a_icbpi/");
listOfFiles = dirFiles.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
    public boolean accept(File dirFiles, String filename) {
        return filename.startsWith("F4_");
    }
});
```

Is it possible to filter for various filenames and concatenate `endsWith` to`startsWith`?

I would like to be able to filter by name according to the criteria `startsWits("F24 _")`, `startsWith("CN _")`, `startsWith("A4 _")` and `endsWith(".txt ")`.

I accept any advice or suggestions to improve my knowledge and the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a logical AND expression `&&` or a regex.

```
listOfFiles = dirFiles.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dirFiles, String filename) {
        boolean endsWith = filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        boolean startsWith = filename.startsWith("F4_") && filename.startsWith("CN_") && filename.startsWith("A4_") && filename.startsWith("Q4_");
        return startsWith && endsWith;
    }
});
```

If you want to use a regex it will looks like this `(F4_|CN_|A4_|Q4_).*(\.txt|\.TXT)`.
You can check how this regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/ddZt1M/1).

```
listOfFiles = dirFiles.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dirFiles, String filename) {
        return filename.matches("(F4_|CN_|A4_|Q4_).*(\\.txt|\\.TXT)");
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of `filename.endsWith(".txt") || filename.endsWith(".TXT");` you can do `filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")`

Answer (score 3):

Make is simple and split the 2 rules, and use logic operators

```
boolean isValidStart = 
        filename.startsWith("F24_") || 
        filename.startsWith("CN_") || 
        filename.startsWith("A4_");
  
boolean isTxt = filename.endsWith(".txt");
            
return isValidStart && isTxt;
```